# How to run sql queries on backend instead of using nohup on linux.

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am looking for a solution for the problem. I am trying to execute one procedure in sqlplus by logging into linux server by using putty.

is there any possibility to run the procedure back end even if i close the putty session when running(in between) the procedure..? Instead of Nohup mode.

I heard, it is possible, because i heard one procedure ran for six days but it was not kept in nohup mode. They directly executed the procedure in sqlplus prompt and they directly closed the putty session, Still it is executing. 
does server will take care of procedure....?

Thanks in advance
Siva

Comment: you can use `screen` http://dasunhegoda.com/unix-screen-command/263/

Comment: Instead of using screen command and nohup mode.

Comment: Yes, you could always kick off a one-off scheduled job using dbms_scheduler. Or, if this is something that is run periodically, create the job and only run it when needed.

Comment: Thanks Boniest, Actually i was looking for another solution. What will happen if i close putty when oracle procedure running on frontend. ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to execute any script on oracle in background. First create a script name test.sql.

1. You have to use '&' which will put it in the background.

   sqlplus username/password @test.sql &
2. execute using nohup command

   nohup sqlplus username/password @test.sql &

And you can close putty session.

Comment: Thanks Shamim, Actually i was looking for another solution. What will happen if i close putty when oracle procedure running on frontend. ? Thanks in advance